Why ignore beginner questions about Kali Linux?
Original question:
"""
I've downloaded 64bit Virtualbox Kali Linux and after launching it I am almost immediately presented with the login screen. I've tried the default virtualbox credentials, kali/kali, root/toor and all blank.
Nothing worked and I can't find the answer anywhere.
"""
This question was not well received. My post was downvoted immediately and people told me that if I asked this question I should use a different distro, but nobody actually answered my question and it was mostly ignored by most.
The password is "osboxes.org" and this is for all distros that you download using the link from the virtualbox website.
I would've ran into the same problem with any other distro, but because I ran into it with kali I get down voted and ignored. Great community.
If someone has trouble with the setup you could answer their question (unless maybe the problem is kali linux specific) and recommend them to use a different distro...
Ignoring/downvoting people because they're "beginners" is going to discourage them from using linux, confuse them and make them feel negatively about the linux community.
So why ignore and even downvote beginner questions about kali linux?
